# How to get element from a collection with _.each()

Tags: underscore.js

I have a backbone collection of models, now I want to access to each model from the collection and do something with it with _.each(), after looking into the underscore documentation, I come up with this first

```
_.each(this.someCollection, function(element) {
    console.log(element);
}
```

but element is `undefined`..., did some further reading and in the second try:

```
_.each(this.someCollection, function(element, index, list) {
    console.log(list.at(index);
}
```

this seem to work and get each model I want, but it seems very complicated to me to just get the element from each iterate. Is there a better/elegant way to do it? and what is first argument "element" good for? One would think it's should actually do what I needed...

Answer (score 1):

`this.collection` returns not a `models array` but object containing properties of particular collection like

```
{length:2, models:(2) [s,s], _byId:{c119: s, c123: s}, _events:{…}, _listenId:"l1"}
```

if you want to access models of a collection, use [models](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models) attribute, which returns you an array of models

```
_.each(this.someCollection.models, function(model) {
    console.log(model.toJSON());
    console.log(model.get('someProperty');
}
```

or use straight [toJSON()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) on collection like

```
_.each(this.someCollection.toJSON(), function(model) {
    console.log(model);
    console.log(model.someProperty);
}
```